# New Google Maps - how to launch quickly navigation

Tags: google-maps-navigation, navigation

Recently released [Google Maps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps) doesn't have a standalone app for Navigation which was quick to use - only one tap and voice recognition to start. It takes at least four taps in new Maps to navigate, which is not good to operate while driving. Google Now is not on devices with ICS and below (still majority).

How to start navigation quickly by one tap in current Google Maps? (Google Now is not supported)

```
Observed on: Google Maps version: 7.02 (700021001), Android ICS 4.0.4, Sony Xperia Active
```

[image: Previous standalone app disapeared]
[image]

Previous standalone app on left started navigation immediately after speaking the destination. 
New Maps app on right takes 4 taps to small nav icon, edit, mike, start and doesn't show alternatives if voice recognition is poor.

Comment: There is a shortcut to navigate to a defined destination. Any option to shortcut/widget to voice-recognition for navigation or similar?

Comment: I have a "Navigation" icon in my app drawer, which brings me to Google Maps with the "starting point" and "destination" fields front and center. Do you not?

Comment: @AlEverett that icon disappeared from my phone with the recent Maps update. If you look around forums etc it looks like 50% of people had the separate icon removed, 50% kept it, even for same model/OS phones on same networks.

Comment: @GAThrawn: I'll consider myself lucky, then.

Comment: @myneur: It would be helpful for you to [edit] your question to include the device and the version of the OS. (It wouldn't hurt to have the version of Maps you're using, too.)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for english is to use Voice Commands. Tap on a mike of a Google Search widget and say „navigate to ‚desired destination‘“.

In other languages you can find a voice assistant like [Antelli](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.shawn.antelli) for Czech who can launch the navigation for you the same way but in your language. (Set it to listen immediately after launch.)

Or with English UI language you can say the command phonetically in your language set for Speech recognition (at least on Android 4.4). If you tell it well so the recognition writes the english word, the voice command will work.

Comment: It does not allow me to add an image how it looks: [link](http://cdn-static.zdnet.com/i/story/61/56/006780/voice-actions-navigate-directions.jpg)